# Get extact line which have syntax error in plantUML

Tags: sequence-diagram, plantuml

Greeting, may peace be upon you.
I am using mac OS with VS code, by this I mean I use plantUML as an extension.
I have 0 experience with this, I used app.diagram before this.

```
@startuml shortform
title shortform
actor faris as  user
control x as SOA


database Doc MS as Doc service

control miniapps as app

database google
collections EDA
EDA -> SOA : whitelisted data
@enduml
```

I have tried to comment on what I think is invalid syntax, reading the [doc](https://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram).

but it still yield:

> Error found in diagram shortform
> ERROR
> 3
> Syntax Error?
> Some diagram description contains errors

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't get error details, but you can see the error online at https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/JOzB3i90243td88BU04NfatgqhZe2N1AMvBfq01LZ-_CndH1-F1U29q7MHnRHb_LObRR82GodtfAeOOpcJYI8nxE1abBc6Ryjj7ux05Weg0NEUEW2HzZMxIgqcz937zbaoAqxzw0ca_Yehfahc3Ed4AqEDw77chWvTQku1K_gmHdyU09cmWTbwa-y0C0

Comment: thanks, leave it open. I suspected it on the extension part. Have a good day.

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo did you solve it? Looks like `Doc MS` needs some quotes  (i.e. `"Doc MS"`) and `Doc service` should be one word (i.e. like `DocService` or `Doc_service`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overwhelmed when posting the question, you need a little break or a good night's sleep.

When you populate your diagram the error message located on the visual studio output window will change!

> Error found in diagram Callback from LOS
> ERROR
> 9
> Syntax Error?
> Some diagram description contains errors

The number **9** is referring to your invalid syntax line, which needs to be corrected.

Specific to your code @albert comment should solve it. Note that you export the diagram to a PNG file. the PNG file also contains the debug messages.